# Prevent a function after specific event in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, scroll, preventdefault

So I'm attaching the scroll event to the $(window) like:

`$(window).bind('scroll', function() {});`

In it, is a form which a user can fill out as it follows them down the page (however long they scroll for). After they have filled out the entire form, I'd like to have it stay in it's place until it goes back up to it's previous position again.

Ideally, I think that just preventing the function from being called further would do the trick.

I was thinking of unbinding the scroll event, or using e.preventDefault(), but I'm not quite sure what I should be looking for.

Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: Are you looking for an event you could use to trigger the `unbind`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you'll need to `.unbind` scroll when some inputs are filled in?!